# Why do list initialization cause a Seg fault?

Tags: c++

I was debugging an undefined behavior of my application. Today, I had a chance to try out `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address` flags, and as usual I went ahead compiled my application. Turns out, it found something at run time and it printed out this log,

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==502288==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x0000004ce04b bp 0x611000000b98 sp 0x7ffc441a5bf8 T0)
==502288==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==502288==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #0 0x4ce04b in llhttp__on_message_begin /home/llhttp/src/native/api.c:144:3
    #1 0x4ce4f4 in llhttp__internal__run /home/llhttp/build/c/llhttp.c:14590:13
    #2 0x4ce3e1 in llhttp__internal_execute /home/llhttp/build/c/llhttp.c:14624:10
    #3 0x4c8661 in HTTPTransport::initialize() /home/example.cpp:70:29
    #4 0x4c890f in main /home/example.cpp:76:12
    #5 0x7f09e9f590b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
    #6 0x41d53d in _start (/home/example+0x41d53d)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/llhttp/src/native/api.c:144:3 in llhttp__on_message_begin
==502288==ABORTING
```

I eventually figured out what causing this. Here it's,

```
class Connection : public HTTPTransport
{
public:
    llhttp_t httpParser;
    llhttp_settings_t httpParserSettings;
    sessions session;

    bool auth;
     
    // This line causing it but if I remove it everything works.
    Connection() : auth(){}
};
```

But I found that if I remove the unique_ptr and go to direct initialization of the class, the line has no effect, thus segfault.

Interestingly, this does not happen if I use unique_ptr and remove that line, after that everything works.

I've also tried using an in-class member initializer approach in the class; but it just doesn't work and throws the same seg fault.

I am compiling this on Clang compiler and targets C++17.

To summarize, here are the things I've tried, but did not affect the seg fault in any way,

- In-class member initialization
- Direct initialization of the class instead of `unique_ptr`
- Removed inheritance that this class had with `HTTPTransport` base class

I am aware that `std::make_unique` doesn't call the class list initializer, but the fact is that I'm getting same seg fault with direct initialization of the class, and I initialized it like this,

```
Connection currentConnection;
```

Minimal Reproducible Code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "llhttp.h"

class HTTPTransport
{
public:
    struct sessions
    {
        std::string url;
    };

private:
    static int handleOnUrl(llhttp_t *ll, const char *buf, size_t len);

public:
    void initialize();    
};

class Connection : public HTTPTransport
{
public:
    llhttp_t httpParser;
    llhttp_settings_t httpParserSettings;
    sessions session;

    bool auth;

    Connection() : auth(){}
};
    
int HTTPTransport::handleOnUrl(llhttp_t *ll, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
    sessions *session = static_cast<sessions *>(ll->data);
    session->url = std::string(buf, len);
    return 0;
}

void HTTPTransport::initialize()
{
    auto currentConnection = std::make_unique<Connection>();

    llhttp_init(&currentConnection->httpParser, HTTP_REQUEST, &currentConnection->httpParserSettings);

    /* Set callbacks */

    currentConnection->httpParserSettings.on_url = handleOnUrl;
    currentConnection->httpParser.data = &currentConnection->session;

    std::string res = "CONNECT [2607:f8b0:4008:80c::2004]:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [2607:f8b0:4008:80c::2004]:443\r\n\r\n";

    enum llhttp_errno err = llhttp_execute(&currentConnection->httpParser, res.c_str(), res.length());
}

int main() {
    HTTPTransport Server;

    Server.initialize();

    return 0;
}
```

You will need `llhttp` parser library to build this. You can find it at [Github](https://github.com/nodejs/llhttp).

Worth adding that the behavior is still the same even If I didn't use an unique_ptr

Comment: Probably relevant: without the constructor declared, your `class Connection` might be an [aggregate class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Who deleted that answer about res's end of life?

Comment: The answer author deleted it. It's probably not a problem, since I doubt llhttp stores a passed raw `const char*` pointer rather than copying its contents.

Comment: Which constructor should I declare? and on where?

Comment: It's strange the compiler didn't caught it until I put that flags. Actually, parsing worked but an undefined behavior happened at range loop where it loops only over few items.

Comment: Ensure `auth` is default-ininitialised using an in-class member initialiser: `bool auth{};` - and then you won't need to worry about whatever ramifications the user-declared constructor is having on other class operations.

Comment: @underscore_d Well, I just tried your idea and it has same seg fault.

Comment: `std::make_unique<Connection>()` will value-initialize a `Connection` object. Without a user-provided default ctor this means zero-initialization (followed by default-init). But with one there is no zero-init. Not sure if this makes a difference in your case...

Comment: @TSmith I've tried without an unique_ptr and it outputs same seg fault.

Comment: @TSmith It's good to know that one too. I didn't aware make_unique doesn't call init list at all.

Comment: Can I rule out this as a compiler bug?

Comment: @jeffbRTC It's very unlikely to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @IlCapitano What likely the issue is then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your default constructor you're not initializing `httpParserSettings`, which means it will have garbage data when constructing a `Connection` object, and ultimately `llhttp_init` will try to use that garbage data.  To fix this, value initialize all members in the default constructor:

```
class Connection : public HTTPTransport
{
public:
    llhttp_t httpParser;
    llhttp_settings_t httpParserSettings;
    sessions session;

    bool auth;

    Connection()
        : httpParser{},
          httpParserSettings{},
          session{},
          auth{}
    {}
};
```

or provide member initializers:

```
class Connection : public HTTPTransport
{
public:
    llhttp_t httpParser{};
    llhttp_settings_t httpParserSettings{};
    sessions session{};

    bool auth{};
    // no constructor needed in this case
};
```

The reason it worked with `Connection` having no default constructor is that `std::make_unique<Connection>()` value initializes the allocated object if there's no user-provided default constructor.

Comment: Same would go for all other member variables, presumably (at least if they are basic or aggregate). Basically, one should never write classes where it's even remotely possible that any member can go uninitialised. Anything of basic or aggregate type, stick a `{}` at the end of the member declaration, to avoid any chance of that.  IMHO! (Might as well get into the habit of writing it for all members, even!)

Comment: @IlCapitano It works. Do I have to put {] to end of std::string, std::vector ones too (I have these in real app on this class)?

Comment: @underscore_d I singled out `httpParserSettings` because `llhttp_init` seems to be used to initize `httpParser`, so it's not strictly necessary to value initialize it.  On the whole I agree with you though, one should always initialize members.

Comment: @jeffbRTC You don't _have_ to as the default constructor will run regardless, but it's good practice to stick `{}` at the end of all members.

Comment: @jeffbRTC You don't have to, because 'real' (well programmed, non aggregate, etc.) classes will never be uninitialised and will call the default ctor even without `{}`, but it might be a good habit to get into anyway - as it'll mean you're writing `{}` more, and hence less likely to forget it later for a basic/aggregate type. Plus, it'll mean you're not at the mercy of anyone whose class you use, who themselves might one day forget to initialise such a member and give your code UB!

Answer (score 0):

```
// This line causing it but if I remove it everything works.
```

Check this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Since you need `Connection` objects to be movable (via std::unique_ptr) but not copyable, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
{
public:
    llhttp_t httpParser;
    llhttp_settings_t httpParserSettings;
    sessions session;

    bool auth;

    Connection() : auth(){}
    ~Connection() = default;

    // Non-copyable
    Connection(const Connection&) = delete;
    Connection& operator=(const Connection&) = delete;

    // Movable
    Connection(Connection&&) = default;
    Connection& operator=(Connection&&) = default;
};
```

EDIT: You seem to have only defined the default-ctor though, so I'm not sure that's the issue...

Comment: Why do I have to define ~Connection() explicitly?

Comment: Your solution doesn't works. It outputs same seg fault!